# File I/O Exception not found when deploying clickonce installer C#

Tags: c#, xml, clickonce

I have some code that's been working great. I do a piece where I write to an XML file and when I build this and run the .exe from the Debug folder, everything writes without issues. The problem comes when I publish the installer, I get an IO error, file not found exception.

## Piece that writes to XML

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Injects new user data into credentials XML
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    /// <param name="xmlSource"></param>
    public static void AddUser(string username, string password)
    {
        string xmlPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\Credential.xml");
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
        XElement user = doc.Element("Users");
        user.Add(new XElement("User",
                   new XElement("username", username),
                   new XElement("password", password)));
        doc.Save(xmlPath);
    }
```

The xmlPath takes the current dir and append the `Data` dir and finally links to the XML file. What would cause this to crash only when I do the clickonce installer? Do I need to change the resource type to something special?

Comment: Try outputting your path to a log (or error message). I'd guess that CurrentDirectory isnt what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to get the actual path of Assembly? like below

```
var path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var dir= Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
var youdatafolder = Path.Combine(dir, "/Data");
```

You could try catch the IOException and see what the folder is looking for with current code. it may give you some hint.